# Sequence of events $\{C_n\}_n\in\mathbb{N}$: why $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{m\ge n}C_m\right)\ge\sup_{m\ge n} \mathbb{P}\left(C_m\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, inequality, proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum

Let us start from probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{C},\mathbb{P})$ and a sequence of events $\{C_n\}$. I know that:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{m\ge n}C_m\right)\ge\mathbb{P}\left(C_m\right),\text{ for each $m\ge n$}\tag{1}$$

At this point, why could I state that:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{m\ge n}C_m\right)\ge\sup_{m\ge n} \mathbb{P}\left(C_m\right)\tag{2}$$
?

---

Maybe it is extremely more trivial than I am thinking now. My doubt arises from the fact that, by def., supremum of a sequence does not necessarily belong to the sequence itself.

Comment: For a (bounded) real sequence $\{a_n\}$, $\sup a_n$ is the smallest value $s\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $a_n\le s$ for all $n$. So if $a_n\le z$ for all $n$, $z$ must be greater or equal $s$.

Comment: Fantastic explanation, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if $a_{n}\leq M$, it means $M$ is an upper bound of $a_{n}$. 
By definition, $\sup(a_{n})$ is the smallest upper bound, so $M\geq \sup(a_{n})$. Same applies here.

Answer (score 0):

$$A\subseteq B\implies\mathbb{P}(A)\le \mathbb{P}(B)$$ Now $C_m\subseteq \bigcup_{k\ge n}C_k$ for all $m\ge n$, hence $\mathbb{P}(C_m)\le\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{k\ge n}C_k)$ for all $m\ge n$. $\sup_{m\ge n}\mathbb{P}(C_m)$ is the smallest number that is $\ge\mathbb{P}(C_m)$ for all $m\ge n$. Any number that is $\ge\mathbb{P}(C_m)$ for all $m\ge n$, has to be greater than $\sup_{m\ge n}\mathbb{P}(C_m)$.

Comment: Yeah, $\mathbb{P}(C_m)\le\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{k\ge n}C_k)\text{ for all }m\ge n$ is the inequality $(1)$ in my question itself. My doubt is: why 
$$\mathbb{P}(C_m)\le\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{k\ge n}C_k) \text{, for all }m\ge n\iff \sup\mathbb{P}(C_m)\le\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{k\ge n}C_k)  $$? @QED